# SwiftUI not handling @State correctly with List and TabView

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a TabView that contains a List and some other Views. When the user selects an item on the List then changes the selected tabbar, the selected state for the tabbar is not updated, and if the user then changes the selected tabbar yet again, SwiftUI will render both content at the same time.

Here's a video that explains better what's going on:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/g4d0m56tps2ar0w/swiftUIBug.mov?dl=0

And here's the entire code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListView: View {
    @State var items = ["a", "b", "c"]
    @State var selectedItem: String?

    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selectedItem) {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedView = 1

       var body: some View {
           VStack {
               TabView(selection: $selectedView) {
                   ListView()
                       .padding().tabItem {
                           Text("1")
                   }.tag(1)

                   Text("2")
                       .padding().tabItem {
                           Text("2")
                   }.tag(2)

                Text("3")
                       .padding().tabItem {
                           Text("3")
                   }.tag(3)

               }.padding()
           }
       }
}
```

Why isn't SwiftUI respecting the @State for the TabView? This only happens after the user selects an item on the List, if no item is selected everything works fine.

Comment: It is not a state - it is List activation, and it is definitely a SwiftUI bug, so worth submitting feedback to Apple.

Answer (score -1):

you need to change your ListView's `@State var selectedItem: String?` to `@Binding var selectedItem: String`. and then in TabView, `ListView(selectedItem: $selectedView)`